# Zero appears from digit when duplicates removed using new Set

Tags: javascript, join, split, set

I want to remove duplicate digits from `n`. So what I expect is `123456789`. But when I do so using `new Set()` below, I get `1234567890` with zero as the last digit. But there is no `0` in the original `n`.

Can you explain this?

```js
let n=112233445566778899;
console.log([...new Set(String(n).split(''))].join(''));
```

Comment: Try logging `String(n)` first. It's not what you expect

Comment: @Phil yeah String(n) gives 112233445566778900. Why is this?

Comment: Where does `n` actually come from? If you're declaring it, why not simply define it as a string?

Comment: @Phil it's from a problem on the web and it's given as number in a function definition.

Comment: Do you have a link? It's not a value that can be represented in JavaScript as a `Number`. If you copied it from the original, are you sure it wasn't a string or a `BigInt` literal, eg `let n = 112233445566778899n`

Comment: @Phil https://edabit.com/challenge/NXTrfGBXTKg3Z9jkz

Comment: I see you didn't read the comments. It's just a badly worded test

Comment: Just passed the arg as bigint in the solution: https://jseditor.io/?key=pandigital-numbers